# Чат бот в телеграм

Tags: telegram-bot, бот, чат

сама не особо разбираюсь, буду рада если подскажете как реализовать такую задачу. Нужно сделать чат бота в телеграме, который будет получать сообщение от пользователя в заготовленном формате "www.iternetmagazin/тут пишется код товара" и потом пересылал мне это сообщение ссылкой к примеру "www.iternetmagazin/423453"

Answer (score 0):

Вы видимо путаете **stackoverflow** с **freelance** биржей! Тут не решают тестовые задания за джуниоров, а помогают в решении! Покажите что вы уже сделали, как вы мыслили, с какой проблемой столкнулись, что именно не получается. На [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5) тысячи роликов на тему как создать бота. Берите любой и начинайте делайте! Если будут трудности или вопросы, пишите сюда. Если совсем лень включать голову, используйте ChatGPT.